# addEventListener to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I am new to Javascript and I try to add an event listener for each button on every card, but the code make the last card (button) only have the event 'click' so is there's any way to make it happen with innerHTML card
this is the code:

```
let tracksRender = (track) => {

track.forEach(element => {

    //this the card that will add the button for
    let card = `<div class="card">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="image_img" src="${element.artwork_url || 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'}">
    </div >
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="${element.permalink_url}" target="_blank">${element.title}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div >`;
    
    //here i add the card to DOM
    let searchResults = document.querySelector('.js-search-results');
    searchResults.innerHTML += card;

    // store the content of the button 
    let inBtn = `<i class="add icon"></i>
    <span>Add to playlist</span>`;
 
    // created button container 
    let btn = document.createElement("div");
    btn.classList.add("ui", "bottom", "attached", "button", "js-button");

    // added the content of the button 
    btn.innerHTML += inBtn;
    
    // here i add the the event Listener to the button 
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("click");
    });

    //here i add the button to the last card have been created
    searchResults.querySelector(".card:last-child").append(btn);
    
});
}
```

and the structure:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <title>SoundCloud Player</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/main.css'>
    <style></style>
</head>

<body id="soundcloud-player">

    <div class="ui container col">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="js-search-results search-results ui cards">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js'></script>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y73bstju/7/

but it will add the event to the last card only

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle for your problem? Thanks.

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry i don't understand.

Comment: There is a website called jsfiddle.net where you can create a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Then we could visit that and see what the problem is, which would make solving it a lot easier.

Comment: @LajosArpad this is the link (https://jsfiddle.net/y73bstju/7/) and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that theoretically the object should have the event, but the behavior we experience is that whenever another write happens at the relevant section of the DOM, the event handler is lost, which is the reason the last element has the click event. So, let's write first into the DOM and only when we are done with that should we add the event listeners, like:

```
let SoundCloudAPI = {};
SoundCloudAPI.init = () => {
    SC.initialize({ client_id: 'cd9be64eeb32d1741c17cb39e41d254d' });
};
SoundCloudAPI.init();


SoundCloudAPI.getTrack = (inputVlue) => {
    SC.get('/tracks', {
        q: inputVlue
    }).then((tracks) => {
            console.log(tracks);
        SoundCloudAPI.renderTracks(tracks);
    });
}
SoundCloudAPI.getTrack("alan walker");

SoundCloudAPI.renderTracks = (track) => {

        track.forEach(element => {

    //this the card that will add the button for
    let card = `<div class="card">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="image_img" src="${element.artwork_url || 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'}">
    </div >
        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">
                <a href="${element.permalink_url}" target="_blank">${element.title}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div >`;
    
    //here i add the card to DOM
    let searchResults = document.querySelector('.js-search-results');
    searchResults.innerHTML += card;

    // store the content of the button 
    let inBtn = `<i class="add icon"></i>
    <span>Add to playlist</span>`;
 
    // created button container 
    let btn = document.createElement("div");
    btn.classList.add("ui", "bottom", "attached", "button", "js-button", "fresh");

    // added the content of the button 
    btn.innerHTML += inBtn;
    

    //here i add the button to the last card have been created
    searchResults.querySelector(".card:last-child").append(btn);
    });
    for (let btn of document.querySelectorAll('.ui.attached.button.js-button.fresh')) {
        // here i add the the event Listener to the button 
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log("click");
        });
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r84um9pt/

Answer (score 2):

It might help to create elements instead of appending innerHTML:

```js
let tracksRender = (track) => {
    
  // Select the results here, so you wont have to repeat it
  const searchResults = document.querySelector('.js-search-results');

  track.forEach(element => {

    // Create the card, give it its class and innerHTML
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.className = 'card';
    card.innerHTML = `<div class="image">
                          <img class="image_img" src="${element.artwork_url || 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/'}">
                      </div >
                      <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">
                              <a href="${element.permalink_url}" target="_blank">${element.title}</a>
                          </div>
                     </div>`;
 
    // Created the button, give its classes and innerHTML
    const btn = document.createElement('div');
    btn.className = 'ui bottom attached button js-button';
    btn.innerHTML = '<i class="add icon"></i><span>Add to playlist</span>';
    
    // Add the event listener
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('click');
    });

    // Append the button to the created card
    card.appendChild(btn);

    // Add the card to the results
    searchResults.appendChild(card);
    
  });

}
```

Comment: it is one of the think i did but it will add event only for the first button, thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

I think:
you're doing:

```
let searchResults = document.querySelector('.js-search-results');
searchResults.innerHTML += card;
```

Serializing again and again in your div "searchResults"

innerHTML ~erases~ listeners, and probably it is ~erasing~ your previous listeners. Besides, i don't remember where i read that innerHTML script code cannot run (for security purposes)

From https://medium.com/@kevinchi118/innerhtml-vs-createelement-appendchild-3da39275a694

> using innerHTML reparses and recreates all DOM nodes inside the div
> element and is less efficient than simply appending a new element to
> the div. In the above cases, createElement is the more performant
> choice.

Be careful:

Using "append" again and again uses badly browser resources, redrawing many times.
But, you can append in a documentFragment and append it to the div `-js-search-results`

DocumentFragment:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Answer (score -1):

Welcome in the community. In you're code you're adding many classes to button. You can add event Listener to any one of the unique class name which is specifically applied on button element only.

You can replace:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click');
});
```

with:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-button').forEach(el=>{
  el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
 });
});
```

Also, it would be good if you add eventListener out of the loop in which you are appending elements.

Comment: This will keep adding event listeners, even to buttons that already have a listener on it, resulting in firing multiple times per button

Comment: @Emre Thanks for reminding. I've modified my answer and added `event.preventDefault` to avoid multiple event fire.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. The `document.querySelectors('.js-button').addEventListener()` will add an event listener to all buttons when the `tracksRender()` function is fired, correct? But the next time its fired again, all buttons will get the event listener added again. So when you click any button, it will log twice. If the `tracksRender()` is fired for a third time, all buttons will get another listener and log three times, and so on. Its better to add the listener once per button, not to all buttons at once.

Comment: @ LilFlower this method wiil make the complexity On² and i'm trying to make the code light as possible, thanks any way.